# Corrupted files in Git

Tags: git, repository, file-corruption

I have recently removed some folders from my git repos history using the following command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached var' -- --all
```

Unfortunately I cannot pull anymore from this repos, This is the error set I'm getting:

```
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3953, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2810/2810), done.
error: garbage at end of loose object '4b391c2cc93ccc8d2f7262335629a7f81d6bcbe0'
fatal: object 4b391c2cc93ccc8d2f7262335629a7f81d6bcbe0 is corrupted
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: On which linux system did you make the changes?

Comment: I was using windows; now I'm on linux and it works well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some kind soul [wrote a script](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/509180/comments/41) to do this automatically (and more thoroughly), but the process to recovery is basically this:

1. Examine the file that reports garbage, with hexdump.

   ```
   $ hexdump .git/objects/4b391c2cc93ccc8d2f7262335629a7f81d6bcbe0
   ```

   You're looking for a part of the file where there's a huge span of zeros. If there are multiple such spans, I've had good luck (N = 2) when considering just the first giant set of zeros, even when they included small runs of nonzero data. This is the "garbage" that git is complaining about.

   ```
   ...
   0000500 0532 0302 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    # <-- Beginning here...
   0000510 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
   *
   0001000             # ... almost 3kb of zeros.
   ```

   You can determine from this the *real* size of the object. Here, it would be 0x504 or 1,284 bytes.
2. Make a backup copy of the object. In case you pick the wrong set of zeros, you can try again with a different set.

   ```
   $ cp .git/objects/4b391c2cc93ccc8d2f7262335629a7f81d6bcbe0 ~/old_4b391c2cc93ccc8d2f7262335629a7f81d6bcbe0
   ```
3. Truncate the file to its appropriate length.

   ```
   $ truncate -s 1284 .git/objects/4b391c2cc93ccc8d2f7262335629a7f81d6bcbe0
   ```

The corrupt object should now be fixed. Assuming it was the only one, cloning/pushing/pulling the repository should now work as expected.

Citing my sources, I believe I have experienced the same issue, but in my case using Ubuntu 10.4 (kernel 2.6.32-23-generic). In this case, it is a filesystem bug that has not been tracked down yet. There is an open issue on [ecryptfs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/509180) on this subject and also a [related usenet thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/146847). Along the way to a solution, I found a [handy answer and summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure) on StackOverflow. The [linked article](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt) was very interesting, though I ultimately went a different way.

Comment: HUGE thank you for this answer. git-remove-trailing-garbage.py (your link with text "wrote a script", above) saved my bacon when I ran into that same ecryptfs bug you mentioned!